# Does Kafka Streams aggregation stage serialize and deserialize each single element?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I noticed that the `aggregate()` stage seems to serialize/deserialize every single element, even though it emits a result periodically.

```
  streamBuilder
      .stream(inputTopic, Consumed.`with`(keySerde, inputValueSerde))
      .groupByKey(Serialized.`with`(keySerde, inputValueSerde))
      .aggregate(
        () => Snapshot.Initial(),
        (_, event, prevSnap: Snapshot) => {
          // ...
        },
        Materialized.as(stateStoreName).withValueSerde(snapshotSerde)
      )
      .toStream()
```

I was hoping that the key-value store works in memory until there's a write on commit. It looks like not only writes are made for every single update, but there are also reads which deserialize back. Can someone explain how does this work underneath and if I should be concerned about performance?

Answer (score 3):

Your observation that data is always (de)serialized is correct, even if all data is in-memory. All stores in Kafka Streams are based on `byte[]` arrays to allow for proper memory management. Deserialized on-heap Java objects have unknown size and make memory management hard and memory usage unpredictable.

Your store would still work in-memory, and writing to disk only happens when necessary and on commit.